# Autofac Generic Delegate Factory Registration

Tags: c#, generics, dependency-injection, autofac, factory

For my `IRequest<T>` implementations I want to register a generic delegate factory using `Func<>` to be injected into objects using Autofac. I cannot figure out a way to do this, is it possible?

```
class IoC {
  IContainer Container => {
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterType<IntRequest>().As<IRequest<int>>();
    builder.RegisterType<StringRequest>().As<IRequest<string>>();

    // TODO: register delegate factory for requests

    return builder.Build();
  }
}

class Context {
  // Not sure what this Func<> would be
  private Func<> _factory;

  // _factory to be injected here
  Context() {}

  string GetString() => _factory<string>().Execute();

  int GetInt() => _factory<int>().Execute();
}

class IntRequest : IRequest<int> {
  int Execute() {
    // code
  }
}

class StringRequest : IRequest<string> {
  string Execute() {
    // code
  }
}

interface IRequest<T> {
  T Execute();
}
```

Comment: What actually do you want to be injected: `Func<IRequest<T>>`?

Comment: Yes, something along those lines

Comment: I think you don't need any other registration. Autofac is able to automatically create factories when `Func<T>` is requested.

Comment: Not sure I understand, I want to be able to create both `StringRequest` and `IntRequest` by injecting one factory. So I can create the an instance by calling something like `factory<int>()` or `factory<string>()`

Comment: can you add a sample code where the factory should be injected to?

Comment: I have added a context class, I am unsure what type `_factory` would be

Comment: I see. But I can't imagine what type should `_factory` have.   
However - here your context has two methods - `GetInt` and `GetString`, so you can actually add `Func<IRequest<int>> intRequestFactory` and `Func<IRequest<string>> stringRequestFactory` to cosntrctor and AutoFac will inject them.  Another possibility - you can turn `Context` also to be generic, say `Context<T>` and have `Func<IRequest<T>> requestFactory` in contructor injected.

Comment: If you can't get a repro to work _without_ Autofac (e.g., you can't get a C# type or function to be a "placeholder" and get your code to compile), Autofac won't be able to bridge that gap. Autofac just automates it; it still has to obey the rules of the language.